# PHP Yii- Clicking list then display complete data of list clicked in modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii

I've just started working with Yii framework. And I was having a hard time
passing data of list to a modal when clicked. I was already using AJAX. 
My modal is in the same view with my list. 
So my code basically looks like this..

This is my view:

```
<div id="view-data" class="modal viewdata-modal fade hide" data-backdrop="true">
<!-- the full data from clicked list -->

</div> 
.
.
.
<div>
<!--table--list of something-->

    <tr class="odd">
        <td class=" "><a onclick="checkData('<?php echo $inbox_list_data['id']; ?>')" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-mail" ><?php $list_data['title'];?></td>                                               else echo $msg; ?></a></td>
        <td class=" "><?php $date = $list_data['date_updated']; echo date('Y / m / d',strtotime($date));?></td>
    </tr>

</div>
```

Then this is my JS:

```
    function checkData(id) {
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : "/link/data/view",
            data : {'id' : id},
        });
    }
```

Then in my controller:

```
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        //getting list from db then render

    }

    public function actionView()
    {
        $this->initPage();
        Helper_Site::supportMessageJS();

        if(isset($_POST['id']))
        {
            $id = $_POST['id'];
            //use the id for getting the data then ...??
        }

        //I cannot render since i'm passing it to modal and i dont have to refresh the page right?
        $this->renderPartial('index', array('data1'=>$data1, 'data2'=>$data2, true, false);

    }
```

So how can  i pass my data back to my view? But i'm also not sure of my JS...

Any idea is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: May be this URL you http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/49/update-content-in-ajax-with-renderpartial/

Comment: is this applicable to one view only? that link is using two views..

Comment: yes,you can use same view.

Comment: i added renderPartial and still no display in my modal..I updated my code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update your view container after ajax is done.

```
function checkData(id) {
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : "/link/data/view",
            data : {'id' : id},
        }).done(function( data ) {
          $("#view-data").html(data);
       }
      });
}
```

Comment: still i have to use renderPartial in my controller?

Comment: yes, renderPartial provide output form server side and then you have to put into your client side html